# Xamarin Reactive Observable Throttling doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, observable, reactive, xamarin.essentials

I want to throttle the orientation sensor of `Xamarin.Essential` as follows:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<OrientationSensorChangedEventArgs>(
    ev => OrientationSensor.ReadingChanged += ev,
    ev => OrientationSensor.ReadingChanged -= ev
)
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
.Subscribe(x => { onOrientationChanged(x.Sender, x.EventArgs); });

OrientationSensor.Start(SensorSpeed.UI);
```

The handler method has the following signature:

```
void onOrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationSensorChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

If I leave out the `Throttle` method, everything works great. With the `Throttle` in there, nothing fires at all.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you want to rotate the screen, but not immediately - only after 500ms pass.
In such case you should use `.Debounce(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))` instead of `.Throttle` on line 4.

The difference between Throttle and Debounce is such:

- Debounce will take all the incoming events during 500ms period and
  will emit only the last one.
- Throttle works a little different: it takes the first event during
  500ms period and emits it; all the other events are ignored until
  500ms period passes. Because of this you receive only a small change
  as a first event, which is not enough for a rotation to complete.

Comment: The purpose behind is not a screen rotation. I actually do want to ignore events for a certain amount of time. My implementation/library doesn't seem to have a `Debounce` method anyway. I think my problem is the usage/syntax, simply because nothing fires at all.

Comment: Ok, I figured out it's the timing itself. 500ms seems to be way too long. If I go down to 50ms, it works.